# Aligning data arrays by closest time

Tags: matlab, indexing, time-series, sampling, closest

I have 2 data vectors with corresponding time vectors. This data is sampled nearly simultaneously but they have slightly different timestamps (from machine precision transmission delays etc.). One or both of the data vectors experience occasional data losses & occasional double samples due to telemetry issues.

I want to match up the data arrays to where their times match to perform some math operations between them. Essentially remove points from `y1` & `y2` where they do not have corresponding times `x1` & `x2` (within about 1/2 of the sample rate to be considered a match).

Note I do not want to interpolate `y1` & `y2`

```
%Sample time stamps: Real ones are much faster and not as neat.
x1 = [1  2 3 4 5 5.1 6   7   8       10  ]; %note double sample at ~5.
x2 = [.9       4.9    5.9 6.9 8.1 9.1 10.1]; %Slightly different times.

%Sample data:  y is basically y1+1 if no data was missing
y1 = [1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8    10];
y2 = [2       6   7 8 9 10 11];
```

[image: Sample Plot]

So the result should look like:

```
y1_m = [1 5 6 7 8 10];
y2_m = [2 6 7 8 9 11];
```

**What I have so far:**  I used `interp1` to find the closest time points between the 2 time arrays. Then got the time delta between them like this:

```
>> idx = interp1(x2,1:numel(x2),x1,'nearest','extrap')
idx =
     1     1     2     2     2     2     3     4     5     7

>> xDelta = abs(x2(idx) - x1)
xDelta =
    0.1000    1.1000    1.9000    0.9000    0.1000    0.2000    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000    0.1000
```

Now what I *think* I need to do is for each unique `idx` find the min `xDelta` and that should get me all the matching points.  However, I haven't come up with a clever way of doing that... It seems like `accumarray` should be useful here but so far I failed at using it.

Comment: Interesting question! Please first write this in loop form, it might be fast enough, and more readable. A vectorized solution could involve making a single array with indices and deltas, sorting it by rows (so you sort first by indices, and for equal indices you sort by delta). Next, pick the first element for each index, and find the corresponding location in the unsorted array. I think `unique` on the sorted index column would pick the first of each index?

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I started to make a loop and it started to get complicated with indices of indices & find statements ... it was ugly.  Anyway I got a working vectorized solution based on your comment.  If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it otherwise I will submit mine so this doesn't go unanswered.  Thanks.

Comment: It'll be easier for you to write this answer. I don't think that my sketch above is a full answer, I'd have to put in effort to write an answer, and you've already done that effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution based on @Cris Luengo's comment on the original question.

It uses a `sortrows` & `unique` to get the lowest time error for each pairing of data points.

```
%Sample time stamps: Real ones are much faster and not as neat.
x1 = [1  2 3 4 5 5.1 6   7   8       10  ]; %note double sample at ~5.
x2 = [.9       4.9    5.9 6.9 8.1 9.1 10.1]; %Slightly different times.

%Sample data:  y is basically y1+1 if no data was missing
y1 = [1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8    10];
y2 = [2       6   7 8 9 10 11];

%Find the nearest match
idx   = interp1(x2,1:numel(x2),x1,'nearest','extrap');
xDiff = abs(x2(idx) - x1);

% Combine the matched indices & the deltas together & sort by rows.
%So lowest delta for a given index is first.
[A, idx1]    = sortrows([idx(:) xDiff(:)]);
[idx2, uidx] = unique(A(:,1),'first');
idx1         = idx1(uidx); %resort idx1

%output
y1_m = y1(idx1)
y2_m = y2(idx2)


y1_m =
     1     5     6     7     8    10
y2_m =
     2     6     7     8     9    11
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Here is a solution based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough idea which you could likely improve upon, using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [`ismembertol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html):

```
function [y1_m, y2_m] = q48723002
%% Stage 0 - Setup:
%Sample time stamps: Real ones are much faster and not as neat.
x1 = [1  2 3 4 5   5.1 6   7   8       10  ]; %note double sample at ~5.
x2 = [.9       4.9     5.9 6.9 8.1 9.1 10.1]; %Slightly different times.

%Sample data:  y is basically y1+1 if no data was missing
y1 = [1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 8    10];
y2 = [2       6   7 8 9 10 11];
%% Stage 1 - Remove repeating samples:
SR = 0.5; % Sampling rate, for rounding.
[~,Loc1] = ismembertol(x1,round(x1/SR)*SR,SR/2,'DataScale',1);
[~,Loc2] = ismembertol(x2,round(x2/SR)*SR,SR/2,'DataScale',1);
u1 = unique(Loc1);
u2 = unique(Loc2);
x1u = x1(u1);
y1u = y1(u1);
x2u = x2(u2);
y2u = y2(u2);
clear Loc1 Loc2
%% Stage 2 - Get a vector of reference time steps:
ut = union(u1,u2);
%% Stage 3 - Only keep times found in both
[In1,Loc1] = ismembertol(ut,x1u,SR/2,'DataScale',1);
[In2,Loc2] = ismembertol(ut,x2u,SR/2,'DataScale',1);
valid = In1 & In2;
%% Stage 4 - Output:
y1_m = ut(Loc1(valid)); % equivalently: y1_m = ut(valid)
y2_m = y1_m + 1;
```

```
ans =

     1     5     6     7     8     9
```

See also: [`uniquetol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uniquetol.html).

Comment: That is a interesting approach.  I was not aware of the function `ismembertol`.  Probably because my company recently just upgraded from 2014b and it is new as of 2015a.  However, there appears to be something incorrect.  As the answer is not correct.  `y1_m` should be  `[1 5 6 7 8 10]`